# Custom HttpModule dependency injection with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, httpmodule, custom-authentication

We are doing some custom authentication and I'm making a custom HttpModule to put some authentication logic in.  Having difficulty wrapping my head around how to get dependency injection to work, since HttpModule requires a default constructor.  I have tried property injection route but I get a 
*the type or namespace name 'Composition' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel'* when trying to use the [Import] attribute on the property.  I have referenced System.ComponentModel.Composition and used the [Import] attribute already for a different class (a custom attribute) in exact same way, I am not sure why it is giving this message for the custom HttpModule.  Maybe this is not the best solution anyways(I am still a DI noob), so I thought it would be a good time to put the brakes on and get some help.

My question is: how to properly do dependency injection for a custom HttpModule using Simple Injector?

Current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace CustomAuthMVC.App_Code
{
public class CustomHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    [Import]
    public IAuthService AuthService { get; set; }

    public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.AuthenticateRequest += this.Application_AuthenticateRequest;
    }
}
```

I am using Simple Injector.
The project is in .NET Framework 4.6.1, MVC.
The CustomHttpModule is within the App_Code directory.
AuthService type is registered in Global.asax as singleton.  It is used in other places within the application too and needs to stay as such.

Comment: AHttpModule is not created by Simple Injector. Simple Injector has no chance to do anything with this the created instance at this time.

Comment: Steven, I do not understand where Global.GetInstance comes from on the question mine was marked a duplicate of.